# How to check if an OSC listener is running on Android

Tags: java, android, listener, osc

I want to implement an osc listener on Android, Listening on a specific port of a tablet connected to a private network.
I use the illposed java OSC library from
http://www.illposed.com/software/javaosc.html

I've a
`private OSCPortIn testIn;`

I've set a port and have launched the Listening fonction below

```
try {
            testIn = new OSCPortIn(8200);
        } catch (SocketException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        Listening();
```

..

```
public void Listening(){
    Log.d("Listening", "running");
    OSCListener listener = new OSCListener() {
        public void acceptMessage(java.util.Date time, OSCMessage message) {
            Log.d("Listening", "running");
            //en cas de message vide
            if (message.getArguments().length == 0) return;
            //sinon on recupere les elements et on les tries
            Log.d("test", "on a reçu un message");
            Object[] args = message.getArguments();
            //if (args[0].toString().contains("alpha")) Log.i("receiver osc", "Message received!");
            //int one = Integer.parseInt(args[0].toString());
            //Instructions
            if (args[0].toString().contains("test")) {
                //final int Psize = (Integer)args[1];
                Log.d("test", "bien reçu");
                //TODO : start a function in activity
            }
            else if (args[0].toString().contains("PctOpacity")) {
                final int Popacity = (Integer)args[1];
                //TODO : start a function in activity
            }
            else return;
        }
    };
    testIn.addListener("/mail", listener);
    testIn.startListening();
}
```

My min-sdk is "15".

I sent many osc message to the ip of the tablet (on the correct port)but nothings seems to arrive.
 I don't really know if this library is working for this sdk as I had this library run fast and easy with sdk 8 ...

I manage to send some osc data with an oscPortOut and Asynctask.

Is there a way to check if this specific listener is running ?

Comment: silly question, but did you add the INTERNET permission in your AndroidManifest?

Comment: Yes I did.Actually my  oscPortOut (the osc sender object) is working fine. But not the receiver with the listener part.

Comment: The server restart after a reboot of all the computer/tablet involved. Something like a oscportin not close